# How to perform a case insensitive search when lower(field) on the database is not the same as field.downcase in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following simple active record query to search accross database for other people sharing the same company name (case insensitive)

In short:

```
company = "someTHING"
leads.where("lower(company) = ?", company.downcase)
```

Works well no matter the case of the company name.

The problem appeared when one user entered special character for the company

Échos

```
leads.where("company = ?", company) -> 2 results
leads.where("lower(company) = ?", company.downcase) -> 0 result
```

with "à L'Express", it works in both cases

This means that database lower("É") is not equal to É.downcase

```
>> company
=> "Échos"
>> company.downcase
=> "Échos"
```

How can I perform a search that is case insensitive AND can find the result in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the database `lower`:

```
where('lower(company) = lower(?)', company)
```

Comment: Doh! So simple. Loving it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the database's `lower` is probably the best answer, as glebm said. Other options might be to use `ILIKE` or postgresql's regexp features, but those options would probably be less able to use any index on the field and therefore be less performant.